# Vertically Align content in Bootstrap 4 - How do I prevent horizontal overflow on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4, vertical-alignment

I'm having difficulty with my registration page on my login form - I've used Flex and Vertical Align classes provided by Bootstrap 4 to vertically centre my div.

It works perfect on tablets and bigger devices, but I'm having an issue with the content overflowing on mobile devices:
[image: iPhone 6 Screenshot]

Does anyone know a workaround for this? Or would I be better using a different method of aligning my content?

Here is a link to the page in question: http://shaneprice.co.uk/horizontal-overflow/

Thanks in advance for any support on the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class `py-auto` to your content.

In case that you are wondering, `py` means `padding-top`/`padding-bottom`

*[Reference](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/)*

Comment: Lovely! I added my-auto to my column and it's fixed the overflow issue.

Answer (score 0):

This will work too

```
.panel-logo img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
}
```